# Python Comparing two Strings and Determining 'Uniqueness'

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

the title is a mess so bear with me while I explain my question in more detail (or really, it's a set of semi-related questions). I'm compiling a list of certain words from a large text file and storing them in a dictionary as keys with their respective occurrences (integers) as the value. I want to apply several processes to consolidate the dictionary so that 'related' words get lumped together.

First operation is plurals. I see no reason to have a 'cat' and a 'cats' key in the dictionary. Same with car vs. cars and book vs. books and so on. I want to write a function that (upon seeing a new word not currently in the dictionary) checks to see if the new word is a plural form of any key currently in the dict (and vice versa).

```
if new_word ends with s -> check dict for a key that matches new_word[:-1]
else if new_word does not end in s -> check dict for new_word + 's'
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem? (I would obviously have to handle edge cases for plurals...this is very general at this point)

On the same topic, what if I want to determine if words are similar by consulting a database of known suffixes and prefixes and seeing if a new_word is just a previously seen word with a suffix or prefix attached.

I use nltk to handle a lot of other tasks in my program such as splitting into sentences and individual words but I would prefer to write my 'similar-ness' algorithm myself. Thank you in advance for your help guys!

Comment: You may want to consider looking at [stemming and lemmatization](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-iv-stemming-and-lemmatization). There are libraries that can do this for you already - and in a more correct way that you are proposing here.

Comment: Assuming adding an `s` is just pluralizing would mean that `mar` (as in damage) and `Mars` (as in the planet or candy company) are the same word. Same goes `pas` (as in "faux pas") and `pass`. You get the idea.

Comment: Ah I guess there would be more edge cases than I thought. I guess I should realistically rethink my approach. I will take a look at stemming and lemmatization. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by related words get lumped together? There is either X amount of `cat` or Y amount of `cats`, not 2/3 are cat and 1/3 are cats.

Comment: What I meant is my dict would end up looking like {cat : 4, cats : 2 ...

My original idea was to reduce this result to cat : 6 and conclude from this data the word cat in some form has been referenced 6 times.

Comment: Make your dictionary value a structure. Match `(cat)s?` with a regex. Group 1 is they key to the structure. If length of match > length of group 1, you have a plural. In the keyed structure, do your metrics. I recommend a single trie regex to put all your key's and plurals. It is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Do you really want to write this thing yourself? What you're trying to achieve lies in domain of so called string distance metrics and there's a lot of those with pretty complex and sophisticated logic behind it. If you want to undertake that for reason of say learning, fine, but if I were you I'd familiarize myself with this topic as general algo first, here's a good library that does such stuff: https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-median